# jpa(hibernate) one-to-many flush is not flushing the many side collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have this complex data model. Class A has collection of B, C, D types. E is join table between D and C. F is join table between D and B.

I am saving both E and F from D (cascade.All).  Since E contains reference to C and F contains reference to B, I need them both saved (id generated) before I proceed save D.

So this is my order of saving.

1. saveAndFlush(A) (I would expect statement to flush A (B and C) as they should be cascaded from A).
2. save(D) when I run it I am getting the following exception.

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : E.c -> C**

I inspected the collections a.bSet and a.cSet in eclipse before step 2, Those elements in sets dont have Id generated.

I tried splitting step 1 to

1. saveAndFlush(A)
2. saveAndFlush(a.bSet)
3. saveAndFlush(a.cSet)
4. saveAndFlush(a.dSet) but I got the same Exception.

I also tried to move 1,2,3 to different service method with @Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW) but still the same issue.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

```
class A{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<B> bSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<C> cSet = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE , CascadeType.DETACH}, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private List<D> dSet = new ArrayList<>();
}

class B{
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
}

class C{
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
}


class D{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "d", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<E> e = new HashSet<>()

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "d")
    private F f;

    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
}

/*E is join table between D and C*/

class E{
    @ManyToOne
    private D d;

    @ManyToOne
    private C c;
}

/*F is join table between D and B*/
class F{
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="d_id")
    private D d;

    @ManyToOne
    private B b;
}
```

Comment: The error shows that the associations created by you have not been persisted in the database. Also check this mappedBy atttribute in the relation, this shows the name of the owner of the relation and it should be present in the inverse i.e. back references. Also put cascade attribute at the end of owner of the relation.

Comment: Ensure you are setting both sides of the relationship in all cases. a.dSet.add(d); d.setA(a);

Comment: AlanHay  I am setting the relationship both sides. 

But still seeing the issue.

Comment: @VivekSingh cascade is in place already. but does nt work

Comment: mapped by should not be present on the primary relation side, mapped by is used to show the relationship on the inverse side.